# How to separate a textfield into a number format comma in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want the number to be 12,345,678 so when I type in the textfield it comes out. The maximum input value of the textfield is 8 digits.

I used the following code but I can't clear the number after entering 7 digits.

How do I fix it?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    myTextfield.delegate = self
    self.myTextfield.keyboardType = .numberPad

    myTextfield.addTarget(self, action:#selector(textFieldValDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
}

public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return range.location < 8
}

@objc func textFieldValDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
    if textField.text!.count >= 1 {
        let number = Double(textField.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ""))
        let result = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number!))
        textField.text = result!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there's 7 digits and two commas, and the cursor as at the end, `range.location` will be 9. So use:

```
return range.location <= 9
```

That will allow 8 digits and two commas.

But even then, your check is insufficient. The user can move the cursor to the start of the number and enter several more digits. So simply checking the location of the cursor isn't enough. You want to check the length of what the resulting string will be.

Your code also doesn't make any effort to prevent non-numeric text being entered. A user can copy and paste, a user can use an external keyboard. And on an iPad, the `.numberPad` keyboard still shows a normal full keyboard. Never rely on the assigned keyboard.

Summary - update `shouldChangeCharactersIn` to ensure only digits are being entered and look at what the final length of the string will be, the cursor location is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        return range.location < 10
    }
```

8 digits plus 2 commas, that's 10 characters(last with index 9).